# hibernate PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I already found some information about this exception but mine is very strange.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: 
Could not find a setter for property empty in class java.util.List
```

There is no information where is the failure. I use List in my entities but I don't understand where is the failure.

Comment: are you using mapping files? you have your own List object?

Comment: i am using annotations. and i have an Embeddable attribute. I also have a List of this Embeddable attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I use this embedded collection in a super class and override its getter setter in subclass.
The problem was, i had @ElementCollection annotation just in subclass. When i wrote it to superclass, the problem was solved.
thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is trying to persist a List object and telling you there is no `setEmpty(boolean empty)` method on List.

This is caused by a configuration problem trying to create a relationship between two entities.

**Update:**

setEmpty is not needed. The way you've configured your collection on the hibernate entity is confusing Hibernate into trying to persist a List instead of creating a relationship between rows in two tables. You need to correctly configure the one-to-many relationship in question.

Comment: I know that setEmpty will be needed but why? and where? there is no information. which entites should i configure?

Comment: by the way i think the problem is not entity, i have an embeddable class and i have a list of this embeddable in other entity